# Problems with fonts

Tags: fonts, miktex

I'm an average user of LaTeX, but not proficiency.
I'm trying to learn from book templates I've found on the web, but I get this error message:

```
Trying to make PK font ccicons at 1493 DPI...
Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The ccicons source file could not be found.
Running ttf2pk.exe...
miktex-makemf: PK font ccicons could not be created.

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file ccicons): Font ccicons at 1493 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I'm using MiKTeX (over Windows 7), and according to the MiKTeX package manager the "ccicons" package is already installed.

Could you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A quick hint: If you indent LaTeX code (and erorr and warning messages by four spaces, it'll get pretty-printed automatically. The easiest way to get the lines indented is to highlight them and press the `{}` "button" in the row above the editor window. Please post a minimum working example (MWE) that generates the error and warning messages you've received.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the hint. It is difficult (for me) to post a minimal faulty code example (it is quite customized). I think I'd better post the web address were you could find the source for the book. [link](http://people.umass.edu/klement/tlp/)

Comment: @Mico If you prefer a shorter faulty example, the firts code example on this [thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70824/painless-memoir-class-book-template) also issues a compilation error of the same kind, but related to 'rm-qtmr' fonts instead. Regards.

Comment: Doing some research on the topic, I've found my MiKTeX installation doesn't have any `\fonts\pk` folder. Does it shed some light into the problem?

Comment: No. You should have the ccicons fonts available as type1 (and maybe opentype) if they are installed. For example, my install of TeX Live includes `texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/ccicons/ccicons.pfb` among other files for this package. Either the fonts are not actually installed or TeX doesn't know about them. Do you know how to check this? I know nothing about MikTeX.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

As happens from time to time, MiKTeX's installation of the fonts doesn't update the postcript fonts database, in particular `psfonts.map` & friends. These are to be found in `C:\Users\<Your personal account>\AppData\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config` and in `C:\Program Data\MiKTeX\2.9\dvips\config`.

In order to update these files, you just have to launch:

```
initexmf --mkmaps (or updmap)
```

(and additionally `--verbose`, if you want to read what happens)
from the command line.

Forgotten: 1) if you want all those changes work for any user, you also should launch from the command-line as administrator:

```
initexmf --admin --mkmaps (or  updmap --admin)
```

This command updates psfonts.map & friends in C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\…, thus giving access to the font for every user.

2) It also may happen that MiKTeX forgets to mention the font in a file named updmap.cfg, which is located in `C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\config\`. Mentioning the font in `updmap.cfg` is required for the procedure to work. If this is the case, you should edit/create updmap.cfg with the following command-line:

```
initexmf --edit-config-file updmap
```

and  add two lines, say in your case:

```
#ccicons
Map ccicons.map
```

Comment: It may be useful to add that in Windows 7 (and maybe Vista), in order to start a command line with admin privileges, you have to find "Command Prompt" in the start menu, right click it and select "Run as administrator".

Comment: A gold medal to you Bernard

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I had a similar problem with some fonts in the moderncv package. I would have had no idea how to fix it otherwise.

Comment: @Bernard I know this is answer is from a long time ago but this helped me as well and fixed the problem.

Comment: I needed to do this for both everyone `--admin` and the current user (without `--admin`).
Which was the thing that tripped me up -- I was only running it with `--admin`

Comment: This solves my problem: I had a problem of "The txsy source file could not be found". Previously I tried updmap.exe --admin,  but shown "Sorry, but "MiKTeX Fontmap Maintenance Utility" did not succeed.". Seem like a permission problem. After trying "initexmf --mkmaps". The problem is solved.

Comment: It's been over 9 years, I'm on a mac, and `initexmf --mkmaps` still solved the "Trying to make PK font" problem I was having. I'm upset that this bug exists for so long (and apparently across platforms), but happy it was easy to resolve once I managed to pin it down.

Answer (score 2):

If the following error occurs:

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file md-chr7v): Font md-chr7v at 578 not
>   found  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

then just add `\pdfmapfile{=md-chr7v.map}` to the .tex file. 
[courtesy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354722/fatal-error-occurred-no-output-pdf-file-produced#comment872698_354722): [@UlrikeFischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)

Answer (score 1):

In case of similar problems with MiKTeX where `updmap --admin` does not help, try to open the MiKTeX Console/Maintenance as admin user, and under Tasks, call both `Refresh file name database` and `Refresh font map files`. This solved a similar issue for me (with `FATAL miktex-makemf - The fa5free1solid source file could not be found.` in `miktex-makemf.log`).

(Credit to the [answers here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166500/miktex-makemf-the-source-file-could-not-be-found).)