# miktex-makemf: The source file could not be found

Tags: miktex, compiling, source

I m trying to compile file using TeXworks. I use fithesis class because its pre-set class by my university for creating documents.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,final]{fithesis}  
\usepackage[latin2] {inputenc}
\usepackage[T1] {fontenc}
\usepackage{csquot}
\usepackage{mflogo}


\thesistitle{Utoky pomocou fragmentacie IPv6} 
\thesissubtitle{Bakalarska praca}  
\thesisstudent{Michal Gasparovic}    
\thesisfaculty{fi}  
\thesisyear{jar 2014}  
\thesisadvisor{doc. RNDr. Eva Hladka, Ph.D.} 
\thesislang{sk}                 



\begin{document}  
\FrontMatter  
\ThesisTitlePage  

\begin{ThesisDeclaration}  
\DeclarationText  
\AdvisorName  
\end{ThesisDeclaration}  

\begin{ThesisThanks}  
Dakujem ti Brona.
\end{ThesisThanks}

\end{document}
```

Every time try to compile and error like this occur.

> Trying to make PK font fi-logo at 514 DPI...
>   Running miktex-makemf.exe...
>   miktex-makemf: The fi-logo source file could not be found.
>
> Running ttf2pk.exe...
>   miktex-makepk: PK font fi-logo could not be created.
>
> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex.EXE (file fi-logo): Font fi-logo at 514 not found
>   ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
>   texify: pdflatex failed for some reason (see log file).

I have been trying to update FNDB for many times. My updmap.cfg contains Map mdbch.map line and i even tried to run initexmf --mkmaps as an admin but no difference.

Comment: Did you install the fi-logo.mf (it should go in a texmf tree in fonts/source)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: I dont have any fi-logo.mf file. only fi-logo.tfm placed texmf\fonts\tfm\ or fi-logo.514pk placed texmf\fonts\pk\.

Comment: Then find the mf. It exists. I saw it while looking for your class.

Comment: Mr. Ulrike Fischer you are one smart man. Thank you very much. Now it is compiled without any error and even .pdf file was generated. Many thanks again. 

As you told, i just downloaded fi-logo.mf and put it to the right directory and here we go, it works. <3

Comment: @Michal: Just a hint :-) Ulrike is a (smart) woman.

Comment: Where can I find the fonts/source directory when using mikitex?

Answer (score 5):

Find `fi-logo.mf` (https://github.com/liskin/fithesis), copy it to fonts/source and update the FNDB.

Answer (score 2):

Copy fi-logo.mf to C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\source\

Open Settings in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\Maintenance (Admin)

General tab -> Refresh FNDB

Logo should now compile properly.