# Not loadable Fonts: ec-lmr12, ec-lmssbx10, ec-lmss12, ec-lcssby19 (for LaTeX-Template from university; I am new to LaTeX)

Tags: fonts, lm

I installed MiKTeX and TeXnic-Center. I then installed the typesetting of my university (here: http://tubslatex.ejoerns.de/#releases).

I then compiled the .cls-file of the template from the institute with TeXnic(www.winfo.tu-bs.de/hp/upload/vorlagen/ds_latex_seminar.zip).
At this point the following **warnings and errors** appeared:

- "You have requested package `', but the package provides`unitext'"
- Command \@ already defined
- Missing \bein{document}
- Missing number, treated as zero
- You already have nine parameters
- Command \@already definied. Or name \end... illegal
- Font shape `/cmr/m/n' undefined using`/cmr/m/n instead on input line
- The font size ommand \normalsize is not defined
- [...]

When trying to preview the unitext.dvi with the app YAP the following **error message** appeared:
"Not loadable Fonts: ec-lmr12, ec-lmssbx10, ec-lmss12, ec-lcssby19"

[image: "Not loadable Fonts: ec-lmr12, ec-lmssbx10, ec-lmss12, ec-lcssby19"]

**Here is what I have already tried:**

1) I installed the typesetting of the university (see above) manually (meaning I put the folders of the TDS-archive in the right places) and automatically.

2) I used the MiKTeX-Packagemanager to install all(!) packages including the following strings: "lm". I understand that "lm" means latin modern.

3) I used the command (in admin mode): "initexmf --mkmaps"

4) I used the command (in admin mode): "updmap ec-lmr12.tfm".

The **first time** this command seemed to work (didn't return error message in the console), but it didn't solve the problem that the fonts are not loading.

**Second time:** After deinstalling everything and doing it all over again the following error message was returned by the console:

*"log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger .
log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.
Sorry, but the "MiKTeX Fontmap Maintenance Utility did not succeed for the following reason: This utility does not accept non-option arguments.*
[...]"
[image]

Do you have any idea why the fonts are still not loading? I already tried so much and it is still not working, so I would appreciate your help very much!

Comment: Welcome! What does the command `kpsewhich ec-lmr12.tfm` return? You'll need to get a command line prompt to run this. If that gives you the location of the file, it is likely that you need to run `updmap` as yourself and/or with admin rights. MiKTeX doesn't always update the font maps when new font packages are installed.

Comment: The command <kpsewhich ec-lmr12.tfm> returns the location of the file. I then used the command <updmap ec-lmr12.tfm> which seemed to work. There was a lot of output, ending with "updmap: Updating Is-R files".

However, when viewing the .dvi file with the Yap-viewer the error message is still appearing as before. Still, four fonts are not loadable.

But thank you really much for your help and time!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152721/problems-with-fonts.