# TexStudio:TTF to PK has stopped working?

Tags: pdftex

I have worked on the laptop with the company for writing my thesis on TexStudio.Now my contract ended, I have saved the latex files on my private laptop. Nevertheless, I cannot run my latex in the new laptop anymore and shows the following windows each time I try to generate the pdf file.what should I do?

after I let the program install it, I get this error: TTF to PK has stopped working

```
 Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   miktex-ttf2pk.exe
Application Version:    2.9.6300.0
 Application Timestamp: 5b300c05
Fault Module Name:  MiKTeX209-packagemanager.dll
Fault Module Version:   2.9.6727.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 5b2ffc00
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   0000000000046ebe
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
```

Locale ID:    3079
      Additional Information 1: 2e1c
      Additional Information 2: 2e1c6ba893e9d9583e7b30466c4c25e3
      Additional Information 3: e940
      Additional Information 4: e940f62c92600d86c1297cdc078e09fc

Read our privacy statement online:
       http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy           statement offline:
    C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

please help me

Comment: Maybe try this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152749/117534?

Comment: I don't think that I needed ttf to pk in the last 10 years. Without a minimal example it will be difficult to reproduce the issue. But renewing the map files in the miktex console is certainly worth a try.

Comment: I have like the full project, so could you tell me how can I give example?how to renew the miktex console?

Comment: Troy. now I don't have that problem but I cannot see the pdf file besides my editor as used to.

Comment: I have uninstalled it and installed it many times now, still each time i get new errors. is there an alternative for it?