# Textmaker does not generate a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, miktex

I have compiled so many source codes files in latex and it works perfectly. I downloaded another template and run but my texmaker could not generate the pdf of that file. Although I have tried this file in another laptop in texstudio and its perfectly working.  But I don't know why my latptop miktex not producing pdf file?

**Log File:**

`{C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.91/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file gbsnu8a): Font gbsnu8a at 720 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

Comment: Could you please show the log file?

Comment: @JouleV I have edited my post with Log file (just last some code lines). Please ceck it.

Comment: So you are using a font which is not available in your system

Comment: @JouleV then what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have searched the error and found the solution in the below-given link. It's very helpful.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152749/170109

JouleV thank you for help.

Comment: You are welcome! As the answer there answers your question, you should mark this question as a duplicate. Glad to hear that you are able to solve the problem yourself - I can't even find that link.

Comment: In a current miktex you can trigger the update of the map files in the miktex console in the tasks menu (at best in user mode)