# Tufte layout in "Painless Memoir?"

Tags: margins, memoir, geometry, tufte

I'm trying to bring together two styles, the airy Tufte's page layout

[image]

... and Michael OKane's "painless Memoir" document found on this site.

I've tried to edit OKane's template directly; I've tried to use the "geometry package" ... and yet, nothing seems to work.

Here's the striking result of my attempt with geometry:

[image]

Any help would be welcome.
Thank you kindly.

Comment: Could you provide a link to this "painless Memoir" layout/document on this site?

Comment: Here's the link to Okane's template [Michael OKane's Memoir alternative](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100397/90977)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Initial remarks

Firstly, consider what elements of Tufte's book design you want to emulate (the page geometry, the styling of running heads and headers, side notes, different widths and position of floats).

If the answer is "everything, of course" then think seriously about simply using the *tufte-latex* class, which is established, well-featured and includes all of these and more. It also has good manual-cum-examples.

Using *tufte-latex* will be a **lot** less work than reproducing the whole style in *memoir*, especially if you are not very familiar with memoir's many features. Some of the Tufte style, e.g. the different floats, are quite tricky. You should have a good reason for wanting to use memoir.

Secondly, if you must use *memoir*, I would start from scratch, rather than trying to adapt someone else's "simple" template.

Thirdly, if you're using *memoir*, you should use its features to do what you need to do, as its intended to replace or emulate a lot of other packages. For example, you shouldn't be using *geometry* to do the page layout.

## Some Tufte elements in memoir

That said, I have selectively borrowed numerous elements of Tufte's design for my thesis, which is a memoir document, particularly the layout and handling of footnotes. At other points, for example the typeface, the Tufte style is less suitable for my document.

Here are examples of how I've implemented these elements, which I've done partly by reference to code in *tufte-latex*. These may help if you decide to proceed. This isn't a finished project and there are likely better ways of doing some of the following.

Here's what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQqXt.jpg

### Page Layout

Based on an A4 two-side page, measurements from *tufte-latex*.

```
% MEMOIR LAYOUT
\setlength{\baselineskip}{14pt}
\setlength{\normalbaselineskip}{14pt}

% GEOMETRY
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\settypeblocksize{49\baselineskip}{107mm}{*}
\setlrmargins{24.8mm}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{27.4mm}{*}{*}
\setheadfoot{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\baselineskip}{*}
\setmarginnotes{8.2mm}{49.4mm}{\onelineskip}
\checkandfixthelayout
```

### Ragged left body text

```
% TEXT
% ragged2e provides ragged justification with hyphenation
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\AtBeginDocument{\RaggedRight}
\setmpjustification{\RaggedLeft}{\RaggedRight}
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{1.0pc}
\setlength{\parindent}{1pc}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
% linespacing ~ 14pt
\linespread{1.17}
```

### Full-width running headers

Tufte uses loosely-tracked small caps for the running headers, which do look very nice. You will want a font with true small caps, however. I compile with *XeTeX*, so use *fontspec*'s features to set this font up.

```
% LOOSE-TRACK SMALL CAPS
\newcommand\loosesc[1]{%
  {\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=8}#1}}

% PAGE STYLE - HEADERS AND (NO) FOOTERS
\makepagestyle{tufte}
\makeoddhead{tufte}%
{}{}{\loosesc{\rightmark}\quad\thepage}
\makeevenhead{tufte}%
{\thepage\quad\loosesc{\leftmark}}{}{}
% font settings for page headers
\makeevenfoot{tufte}%
{}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{tufte}%
{}{}{}

% use small caps in running headers
\renewcommand*{\memUChead}[1]{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}

% chapters on left, sections on right, without numbers
\makepsmarks{tufte}{%
  \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{}
  \createmark{section}{right}{nonumber}{}{}
  \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
  \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
  \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
  \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
  \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
  \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}

% full-width-headers
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparsep}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{\marginparwidth}
\makerunningwidth{tufte}{\headwidth}
\makeheadposition{tufte}{flushright}{flushleft}{}{}

% use this
\pagestyle{tufte}
```

### All footnotes are sidenotes

```
% text styling of all side footnotes
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\foottextfont}{\footnotesize}
% styling and placement of mark
\footmarkstyle{{#1. }}
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{0em}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{-\footmarkwidth}
% memoir command - do all footnotes in margin
\footnotesinmargin
```

(edit) If sidenotes run off the bottom of the page, use the *marginfix* package. With many sidenotes, the *extrafloats* package might be needed.

### Floats with side captions

Use memoir's own `sidecaption` environment. The ragged-left layout on verso pages is probably not something I will keep.

```
% SIDECAPTIONS
\setsidecaps{\marginparsep}{\marginparwidth}
\sidecapmargin{outer}
\setsidecappos{t}
\renewcommand*{\sidecapstyle}{%
\captionnamefont{\foottextfont\scshape}
\ifscapmargleft
\captionstyle{\RaggedLeft\footnotesize\foottextfont}%
\else
\captionstyle{\RaggedRight\footnotesize\foottextfont}%
\fi}
```

### Full-width floats

```
% FULLWIDTH environment
% The following code should be used *after* any changes to the margins and
% page layout are made (e.g., after the geometry package has been loaded).
\newlength{\fullwidthlen}
\setlength{\fullwidthlen}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\fullwidthlen}{\marginparsep}

% \newlength{\fullwidthlen}
% \setlength{\fullwidthlen}{\marginparwidth}
% \addtolength{\fullwidthlen}{\marginparsep}

\newenvironment{fullwidth}{%
  \begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\fullwidthlen}%
}{%
  \end{adjustwidth*}%
}
```

Comment: +1, very nice answer.  What font did you use for the example on imgur?

Comment: Thanks. It's FF Tisa https://www.fontshop.com/families/ff-tisa

Comment: Thank you very much for the ideas and tricks; they are very useful for my PhD dissertation, the design of which is inspired by Tufte and [Aaron Turon’s dissertation](http://aturon.github.io/academic/turon-thesis.pdf).

Depending on the specific case, the first part of the `fullwidth` environment might need to be different depending on whether the pageis recto or verso, thus one can use `\checkoddpage\ifoddpage\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\fullwidthlen}\else\begin{adjustwidth*}{-\fullwidthlen}{}\fi`. It is recommended to have `\strictpagechecktrue` in the preamble.

Answer (score 2):

Rob Oakes says that;

> The memoir class, by Peter Wilson, may be the Great Start of Africa of LaTeX document classes. In the right hands, it can be used to typeset nearly any type of book imaginable. And it turns out, that with a little bit of trickery, you can use its \marginpar and sidecaption environments to automatically incorporate ragged marginalia into your books and reports.

His [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170713174428/http://blog.oak-tree.us/index.php/2011/03/26/latex01-raggedmarginalia) explains a shorter approach(I prefer that), it is not complete Tufte-Book yet after the mentioned tweaks. However its simplicity is beautiful and inspiring in order to similar tweaks if necessary/desired.

Ps: LyX tricks explained as well.

Comment: unfortunately the referenced article gives `Access denied.` when I try to open it. Could @trblnc fix this.

Comment: Fixed. Please check again.