# Is there a new package to make Tufte style books?

Tags: margins, tufte

I really like the look of tufte books.
But it seems like the tufte-latex package is largely unmaintained,
([Repo not touched](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex) in >1 year, long open PRs and issues)
and [not supporting things like LuaTeX](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex/pull/123).

I'm particularly liking the wide margins, used for sidenotes, diagrams, and bibliography.

Is there another package that provides these?

Comment: Very related: [Tufte layout in “Painless Memoir?”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275565/tufte-layout-in-painless-memoir).

Comment: Yes, KOMA-script, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/295864/4736 . And the maintainer of KOMA-script enhanced the possibilities of scrlayer recently.

Comment: Re KOMA: see: https://3d.bk.tudelft.nl/ken/en/2016/04/17/a-1.5-column-layout-in-latex.html though it is a mix of doing it the KOMA scrlayer and  hacks with packages