# How do I place a colored box in front of a \section*

Tags: sectioning, color, tcolorbox, sections-paragraphs

I'm using the MWE that Jesper Ipsen provided in [the following question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70824/painless-memoir-class-book-template).

I intend to use colored boxes instead of section numbers. My idea was to implement it [as shown in the following question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378678/is-it-possible-to-add-colored-text-spaces-or-colored-boxes-to-a-headrule/378683#378683).

Now the only thing that's left to do is to have an easy way of adding those boxes whenever I create a new section, as shown below:

```
\section*{Time Machines}
```

The idea is to have it appear like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a MWE that shows what you've got so far? Which of the MWE's provided in the linked question do you use?

Comment: The one created by Jesper Ipsen.

Comment: Using `titlesec` package.

Comment: An option could be to create a colored box with `\newcommand\mybox[1][blue]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{2ex}{2ex}}\hspace{0.5em}}` with `\usepackage{xcolor}` package. In text: `\section*{\mybox ABC}
\section*{\mybox[red]Animals}`

Comment: The linked answer of Jesper Ipsen is no MWE (not minimal). General information [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Detailed information for creating a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). Do you like to have always the same colored box or would you prefer changing colors for different sections?

Comment: My mistake. I need to be able to change the colors depending on the section level, but the color of the section need to remain the same throughout the entire document. Like how subsection 1.1 and 2.1 are the same color because of how they're both subsection X.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As skpblack commented, package `titlesec` can be used for this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern, titlesec, xcolor}

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{yellow}\rule{1em}{1em}}
{1em}
{}


\begin{document}

\section{Another day in paradise}

A regular numbered section

\section*{Another night in paradise}

A starred section that has a coloured box

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

For fine tuning of spacing etc., refer to `titlesec` documentation.