# Unused \captionsetup in environment definition

Tags: errors, captions, subcaption

While setting up my bachelor's thesis, I came across a few problems while learning TeX. My mentor delivered the example .tex file, but I prefer knowing the libraries/packages I will be using in further writing. Therefore, I stumbled upon a few warning messages while compiling (related to `caption` and `subcaption` packages):

> *Unused \captionsetup[sub]*
>
> *Unused \captionsetup[table]*
>
> *Unused \captionsetup[figure]*
>
> *For the caption package to function properly with memoir, we will now reset/caption and friends to kernel defaults and then let the caption package take over.*

I have read the documentation and I am aware that some packages and functions should be called right after the `\usepackage`, but I completely lack experience in TeX.

Enviroment snippet:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{memoir}
%matematički paketi

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}     %omogućava postavljanje granica integrala u formulama
\usepackage{amsthm}     %matematički teoremi, leme i sl.
\usepackage{siunitx}        %podrška za korištenje SI sustava mjernih jedinica

%encoding fontova i jezika
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}        %encoding inputa
\usepackage[enc=utf8]{hrlatex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        %encoding fontova koji je prikazan u PDF-u
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{croatian}
\OnehalfSpacing

%paketi tablica, naslova, poglavlja i sl.
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{tocloft}        %upravljanje izgledom tablice sadržaja
\usepackage{pdfpages}       %integracija eksternih PDF-ova
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}       %koristi se za formatiranje tablica sukladno standardu za znanstvene radove i članke
\usepackage{indentfirst}     %dodaje tab za svaku prvu rečenicu odlomka
\usepackage{subcaption}     %koristi se za podnaslove slika, formi i sl.
\usepackage[font=it]{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=above}
\captionsetup[figure]{position=below}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period}

\usepackage{titlesec}   %nadomješta LaTeX makroe za naslove, odlonke, itd.

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}        %podrška za integraciju hyperlinkova
\urlstyle{same}

%grafički paketi
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,patterns}

%misc. paketi

\usepackage{soul} %žuti marker
\usepackage{times}
```

Comment: Take a look to this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70824/painless-memoir-class-book-template.

Comment: The first warning means that you do not have any tables, figures, or subcaptions in the document, so it is not needed to set any formatting for such a caption. The warning will disappear once you put tables etc. in your document. The second warning is a standard message from memoir, telling you that, because the caption package is loaded, the normal caption formatting commands of the memoir class are disabled. Both these messages are normal, and you can use the template without problems (or at least without problems related to these messages).

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SE, of course!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my question was quite simple, honestly. *@Marijn* answered the question in the comment section. Thank you for elaboration and a warm welcome!

> The first warning means that you do not have any tables, figures, or subcaptions in the document, so it is not needed to set any formatting for such a caption. The warning will disappear once you put tables etc. in your document. The second warning is a standard message from memoir, telling you that, because the caption package is loaded, the normal caption formatting commands of the memoir class are disabled. Both these messages are normal, and you can use the template without problems (or at least without problems related to these messages).