# Multi-paragraph abstract using memoir chapterprecis

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, indentation

Having taken note of a way to have author's names and abstracts assigned to each chapter in a `memoir` class document (see [add authors and abstract below memoir chapter title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549084/add-authors-and-abstract-below-memoir-chapter-title)), I've run into a bit of a snag.

I wanted to add a bit of space in the TOC, which works fine. However, if I try to have a multi-paragraph abstract, the indentation works fine in the TOC, but not in the actual chapter; somehow, the instruction to indent seems to get swallowed up.

How can I fix this? MWE and relevant output follow:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newcommand\authorabstract[1]{%
    \chapterprecishere{\mbox{}\\[\baselineskip]#1}%
    \chapterprecistoc{\\[.5\baselineskip]#1\\[.5\baselineskip]}%
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{First chapter}
% this goes into the document and the ToC
\authorabstract{Author\newline\newline First paragraph.\newline\indent Second paragraph.}

Chapter text here.
\end{document}
```

Correct indentation in TOC:

[image]

Missing indentation in the chapter:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memoir` uses the environment `quote`  (no inner indentation) to put together `\prechapterprecis`.

You might add a `\parindent`  to `\authorabstract` to indent the second paragraph.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\newlength{\docparindent}
\setlength{\docparindent}{\parindent} % save document indent

\newcommand\authorabstract[1]{%
    \chapterprecishere{\mbox{}\\[\baselineskip]\parindent\the\docparindent#1}% changed <<<<<<<<
    \chapterprecistoc{\\[.5\baselineskip]#1\\[.5\baselineskip]}%
}   

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{First chapter}
    % this goes into the document and the ToC
    \authorabstract{Author\newline\newline First paragraph.\newline\indent Second paragraph.}
    
    Chapter text here.
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work well! I guess I can understand, given the original intent of `\chapterprecis` why it would have been set up that way. I'm struggling a bit to understand the fix, though. Do I take it that due to the `quote` environment, indents (i.e., `\parindent` length) are set to 0 length and that we are effectively resetting them to the global value with `\parindent\the\docparindent`, similarly to passing a parameter, then?

Comment: @K.G. Feuerherm Thank you for feedback!. Only `\authorabstrac` is modified by adding a non zero indent to #1. `quote` remains unchanged.